# Passing a string from IHttpHandler to Javascript and then to Silverlight

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, ihttphandler

I am using a handler to act as a proxy between a server with a string (actually a xml but I am trying for a string) and my Silverlight app. I have written the handler and it properly collects the string(xml). The problem I am having is converting that string from the JSON into a string that javascript can pass back to my Silverlight code.

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlReturn = new String("");
    function xmlStart() {
        $.getJSON('xmlProxy.ashx', function (data) {
            setXml(data);
        });
    }
    function setXml(data) {
        xmlReturn = data;
    }
    function getXml() {
        alert(xmlReturn);
        return xmlReturn;
    }
```

Silverlight:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("xmlStart");
    string test = (String)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("getXml");

    textBox1.Text = test;
}
```

Just in case the handler code (baseurl taken out for security):

```
namespace HttpHandler_Proxy
{
    public class xmlProxy : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            WebClient getCap = new WebClient();

            string baseurl = "some_url";
            string response = getCap.DownloadString(baseurl);

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            context.Response.Write(response);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am relativity new to both Javascript and jQuery so this may be a trivial question and for that I apologize. On this version of the code it never sets `xmlReturn` to anything other than `""`

I have done other versions but the code is always returned to Silverlight as null/undefined/"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content type is set to json, but you don't seem to be doing any encoding, i.e. turning the response from the server into valid json.  Try adding something like:

```
response = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);
```

Comment: That worked great! Added that and passed the var with String() and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using `$.load` instead of `getJSON` if you don't intend on treating that string as json at that point.

**Edit**

First, you should check the value of `data` inside your success callback (console.log(data)).  Make sure your server-side code is returning what you intend it to.